# Retrieve broken Vietnamese string variables in R

Tags: r, stringi

I have a dataset from Vietnam. But when I read it in R, the string variables are imported incorrectly. I used `stri_trans_general` from the stringi package, however it works on only a few columns.  
I checked the raw dataset and it seems those few columns were broken when the dataset was exported, looking e.g. like this:

```
"Du?c ch?t m?i"
```

I thus obtain strings with `?` or `>` characters instead of actual words.

How I can repair these words in order to obtain the correct Vietnamese words?

Comment: If the data is lost on the source, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: You could try to fix it, by validating the words with missing characters against a dictionary and guestimate the correct Vietnamese word. My hunch is that the characters which have fallen out are "special" ones, i.e. with all kinds of Vietnamese accents. This is not fool-proof and requires a very extensive dictionary (to get all cases of a verb for instance) though.

Comment: @Braiam- Yes, I agree with you

Comment: @Adriaan- That is a great advice. that is a good way around.